# PHP Application with ASP.net

Tags: php, asp.net, shopping-cart

I am very new to web development and would like to ask this question.. might be a silly one :)

I am currently developing a project in ASP.net. One of the main functionality of the site is to integrate a shopping cart. I found the following shopping cart that meets my needs exactly but it is written in PHP (http://scripts.jakweb.ch/dragndropshop/). Is it possible to integrate them together? (Perhaps publishing them on the same server eventually?)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what level of integration you need, you will not be able to run ASP.NET and PHP on the same page request, but yes you can publish them both on the same server and with a bit of creativity you should be able to integrate the two.

**Note** If you need the PHP cart to execute logic in ASP.NET you may need to create a web service.

Answer (score 2):

So long as this shopping cart has a suitable API to add items to the cart and do a checkout, you will be able to make these calls from your asp.net application too.

Most of the trouble with integrating with a php application would be regarding security. Since you would not be able to use asp.net membership directly, you would have to take extra effort to make it secure.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a lot of effort to go to. Have you considered an asp.net shopping cart solution like nopCommerce found here http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx its well featured and I've used it before on a couple of commercial projects with great success. Rather than spending time on integration between PHP and ASP.NET you could put that time and effort into something else more productive during the project like customisation, extesion or presentation of the nop cart system.